# Get number of pages for Word, Excel, Presentation and pdf programmatically

Tags: php, file-upload

I want to allow the user to upload a file of a type shown above (.docx, ppt., pdf) and then present to the user how many pages there are in the uploaded file. Is this possible with PHP for all of these types. If not is there any particular language that you suggest?

Comment: Hi nidis, did you figure it out how to do this? I am looking for the same solution